# Calculation Python

Tags: python, calculation

I'm an absolute beginner in Python, doing the following training task:

"Two friends are eating dinner at a restaurant, the bill comes in the amount of 47.28 dollars. The friends split the bill evenly between them, after adding 15% tip for the service. Calculate the tip, the total amount to pay, and each friend's share, then output a message saying "Each person needs to pay: " followed by the resulting number".

I wrote the code given below but the system is saying there is a calculation error there. What exactly can be the error?

```
bill = 47.28
tip = 15 // bill * 100
total = bill + tip
share = total // 2
print("Each person needs to pay:" + str(share))
```

Comment: the tip should be `bill * 15 / 100`  Then to divide between people use the normal division operator `/` not the integer division `//` Otherwise the waiter won't be very happy if for a total of 21 dollars each person pays only 10

Comment: i would suggest f-strings to retain sanity of the mind

Comment: but *wait*, it's a `print` statment, right? how's about `print("Each person needs to pay:", share)`?

Comment: @rv.kvetch there's nothing wrong in the print. f-strings are preferred but it's perfectly readable how it is now.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki i would disagree, but i guess it's just a matter of opinion

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thank you so much!!! Yes, the problem was using the integer division.

Comment: you have good answers, consider accepting one if it worked for you

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it a little more elegantly with a function:

```
def split_bill_calculator(invoice:float, taxes:int, people:int)-> float:
    """
    Invoice: FLOAT value
    Taxes: INTEGER percent value
    People: INTEGER
    Return: total amount splitted for each person
    """
    add_tip = invoice * (1 + taxes / 100)
    payable_by_each = round(add_tip / people, 2)
    print(f"Each of the {people} guests should pay {payable_by_each}")
    return payable_by_each
```

Answer (score 0):

// is a floored division, ie it will round down the result of the division to the nearest integer. If the numerator is smaller than the denominator, then you’ll get zero as a result of the floored division. Try `tip = bill * 0.15` instead to calculate the tip.